# Angular 6 routing with multiple levels of NgModules

Tags: angular, module, routes, components

I am trying to implement routing in Angular 6 but there are issues with multiple levels of NgModules.

The structure of modules is the following (B and C are children of A):

```
A_Module
  B_Module
  C_Module
```

This is a segment of code from my top-level NgModule:

```
// A_Module
const routes = [
  { path: 'B', component: B_Component },
  { path: 'C', component: C_Component },
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    A_Component
  ],
  imports: [
    B_Module,
    C_Module,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [A_Component]
})
export class A_Module { }
```

B_Component and C_Component are top-level components inside its own modules.

This solution doesn't work as there are no components from B_Module or C_Module declared inside this A_Module. The thing is that inside B_Module and C_Module there are many many components and moving everything to the A_Module is not the solution (that's why modules were made right - to clean and separate the code?).

Any solutions to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export B_Component and C_Component in their Modules.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [BComponent],
  exports: [BComponent]
})
export class BModule {}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [CComponent],
  exports: [CComponent]
})
export class CModule {}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I needed to remove BComponent and CComponent from AModule declarations as well but otherwise - works.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Please mark this as an answer if possible.

Comment: Will do but as you were so fast I have to wait for another 7 minutes :D